# Aumann's notation 8

Tags: notation, game-theory, economics

I have a question about the page 1306 [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/Values%20of%20Markets%20with%20Satiation%20or%20Fixed%20Prices.pdf)
right below A8:
how differs these two (literally the same!) conditions
$\theta <  u_i(x)-p_i $
? So I do not understand "hence also" below A8

Comment: I don´t see a difference between these two expressions as well. It seems that there is a typo. But I couldn´t identify which one is it.

Comment: @callculus Having opened that pdf file, could you also tell me why on the page $1309$ in $B.19$ the last line there $w_n^{'}(y^{mn};z^{mn})=w_n^{'}(\frac{y^{mn}}{k};z^{mn})$ at first glance, so that I don't need to write a new question for this ? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Please ask a new question. I have no Idea. It is hard to understand for me. Not because of the economic part but of the math part. I´ve studied economics and I´m surprised how much math is in this article.

Comment: @callculus Yes, the article is in fact by the Nobel prize winner in economics and mathematician Robert J. Aumann. That's why I'm reading it carefully. Thank you for your attempt.